# Change parent element in CSS

Tags: css

it its possible to select an parent Element by a specific class?

For an example i have an HTML-List:

```
<ul>
    <li>Entry 1</li>
    <li>Entry 2</li>
    <li class="selected">Entry 3</li>
    <li>Entry 4</li>
</ul>
```

All Elements has an bottom border:

```
ul li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FF0000;
}

ul li.selected {
     border-bottom: 1px solid #0000FF;
}
```

How i can tell **over CSS** that the color of the previous element is **blue**?
For little example (i know that `:previous-child` is not valid/exists but it's an little example):

```
ul li.selected:previous-child {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #0000FF;    
}
```

Here is an fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3W7PQ/

Comment: You can't select previous siblings nor parent elements with CSS. You'll need to use a javascript-based solution.

Comment: Maybe you could use `::before`

Comment: `:before` or `::before` is not an solution. With `before` you only going to the start of the element and not the previous.

Comment: Javascript/jQuery is an idea, but i think the best solution (if possible) is, to make it over CSS.

Answer (score 1):

CSS 4 will allow this with [the subject indicator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject), but there's no way in CSS as it exists today to select an element by reference to following elements.

The usual workaround is to have whatever generates your page specify the relationship itself. So, for example, you might have `<li class="before-selected">` followed by `<li class="selected">`.

Comment: Okay, CSS4 is not an option - It's not working on all browsers. Remains to me nothing more than assign the previous element of a class via Javascript. Thanks